# UiCollectionView Cell unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In this function I'm calling `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to notify the collection view that I want certain cells selected:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

//some code here
....
//cell!.contentView.addSubview(pulseView)
        if (strings_chosen[indexPath.row] as! Bool) {
            self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell!.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.grey.lighten1;
        } else {
            cell!.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.white
            self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
...
}
```

However I'm getting `nil` here (for `cell`). Specifically the error is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell:UICollectionViewCell? = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.selected = false; //THIS LINE IS GIVING ME AN ERROR
    strings_chosen[indexPath.row] = false;
    cell!.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.white
    updateDeleteButtonTitle()
}
```

I don't understand why `cell` is nil, I'm pretty sure I'm grabbing the cell at the correct indexPath. Any reason why cell could be nil?

Answer (score 1):

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns `nil` when that cell is not visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

It will be calling cellForItemAtIndexPath inside of didDeselectItemAtIndexPath before the cell is returned inside of cellForItemAtIndexPath, so the cell is nil.

Instead of calling the functions directly try calling selectItemAtIndexPath and deselectItemAtIndexPath.